# Sorting CSV with IP address column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting, ip-address

I have a CSV file with a column of IP addresses, MAC addresses and some other data. I want to sort all of the data by the IP addresses in ascending order

Input:

```
| IP Address   | MAC Address | ID    |
| ---          | ---         | ---   |
| 10.10.10.1   | {mac1}      | {id1} |
| 10.10.10.112 | {mac2}      | {id2} |
| 10.10.10.17  | {mac3}      | {id3} |
| 10.10.10.7   | {mac4}      | {id4} |
```

What I expect the output to be:

```
| IP Address   | MAC Address | ID    |
| ---          | ---         | ---   |
| 10.10.10.1   | {mac1}      | {id1} |
| 10.10.10.7   | {mac4}      | {id4} |
| 10.10.10.17  | {mac3}      | {id3} |
| 10.10.10.112 | {mac2}      | {id2} |
```

Where the IP addresses are in proper ascending order with their corresponding MAC and ID

I have tried using the pandas `Dataframe.sort_values()` which without a key puts the IP addresses in incorrect ascending order because it looks at the IPs as integers and not as IP addresses. I have also tried to use `sort_values()` with the parameter `key=ipaddress.IPv4Address` but I just get a `KeyError`

```
df_new = df.sort_values(df['IP_Address'], key=ipaddress.IPv4Address)
```

I also tried `sorted()` which puts the IP addresses in the correct order and into a list and then when I put that back into the data frame it doesn't sort the corresponding MAC and ID for each IP

Comment: `df.sort_values(by="IP Address", key=lambda x: sorted(x, key=ipaddress.IPv4Address))`?

Comment: key=[inet_aton](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton) from the built in socket module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This this approach using [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```py
new_df = (df.sort_values(by=["IP Address"], key=lambda x: x.str.split(".")
               .apply(lambda y: [int(z) for z in y])))
print(new_df)
```

---

```
     IP Address MAC Address     ID
0    10.10.10.1      {mac1}  {id1}
3    10.10.10.7      {mac4}  {id4}
2   10.10.10.17      {mac3}  {id3}
1  10.10.10.112      {mac2}  {id2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.sort_values(df['IP_Address'], key=lambda x: x.apply(ipaddress.IPv4Address))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Consider taking the [tour].

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use `df.sort_values(by='IP Address', key=np.vectorize(ipaddress.IPv4Address))`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach was valid but failed because the callable that should be passed to `key` must be vectorized (i.e. take a Series as input and output a Series).

You can wrap your call in [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
import ipaddress
import numpy as np

out = df.sort_values(by='IP Address', key=np.vectorize(ipaddress.IPv4Address))
```

An easier and more generic option, could also be to use [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) for natural sorting:

```
# pip install natsort
from natsort import natsort_key

out = df.sort_values(by='IP Address', key=natsort_key)
```

Output:

```
     IP Address MAC Address     ID
0    10.10.10.1      {mac1}  {id1}
3    10.10.10.7      {mac4}  {id4}
2   10.10.10.17      {mac3}  {id3}
1  10.10.10.112      {mac2}  {id2}
```